# Where did I go wrong: Geodesic distance of spheres

Tags: geometry, spheres, geodesic

I am interested in scaling isotropic functions. The functions depend on the geodesic distance $d(x,y)$ on a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I was interested in functions with the argument $\varepsilon d(x,y)$ and my idea was that the point $\epsilon x$ and $\epsilon y$ on the sphere of radius $\varepsilon$ should satisfy
$$ \varepsilon d(x,y)=d_{\varepsilon}(\varepsilon x,\varepsilon y).$$
Is this wrong, allready?

In the next step I  would aim to embedd this sphere of radius $\varepsilon$ in a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ with additional coefficient $x_{d+1}=\sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}$ and still the distance between the points should be preserved.

But this would lead to $\varepsilon \arccos (x^Ty)= \arccos(\varepsilon^2x^Ty-(1-\epsilon^2))$. Which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Why should the geodesic distance be preserved when you embed? The geodesics in the sphere of higher dimension are different.

Comment: I thought if the added component is the same for both points, the great circle connecting the points on the sphere in $R^{d+1}$ should be on the surface of the lower dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct i.e. $d_{\epsilon}\cdot (\epsilon x, \epsilon y) = \epsilon \cdot d_1(x,y)$.

The second is not. Your embedding is not isometric. It embeds (in the special case of $d=2$) a circle into a unit sphere as "a circle of latitude". Route of an airplane flying from (say) Germany to US is not close to a given circle of latitude, but resembles the great circle of Earth over Iceland or even Greenland.

Comment: Thank you I now understand my mistake.

Comment: You are welcome!